# expiration in com.google.common.collect.MapMaker

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I've just download the last release guava

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0-hal</version>
</dependency>
```

and I see that the class MapMaker does not have anymore the method `expiration` which I found it useful and I have not found any replacement method.

Answer (score 3):

See [MapMakerMigration · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/MapMakerMigration):

> All caching related methods on `MapMaker` have been deprecated in favor of similar methods in `CacheBuilder`, and are scheduled for upcoming deletion.

It looks like it was first deprecated in version [8.0](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/8.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) and removed before [13.0](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/13.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).